# Showing that $W=\{p(x)\in\Bbb{R}_2[x]:p(x) = p(−x)\}$ is a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-writing, solution-verification, vectors

I am trying to prove that:
$$
W=\{p(x)\in\Bbb{R}_2[x]:p(x) = p(−x)\}
$$
is, indeed a vector space. I will show that $W$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}[x]$ and hence, a vector space. My proof is as follows:

Let

$$
p(x)=a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3\space\forall a_1,a_2,a_3\in\Bbb{R}
\\
p(x) = p(-x) \text{ iff } p(x)=a_1x^2+a_3
$$

We know that $\Bbb{R}[x]$ is a vector space so in order to show that the set $W$ is a vector space we will show that $W$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}[x]$.

For  $W\subseteq\Bbb{R}[x]$, $W$ must be closed under addition (i) and scalar multiplication (ii).

(i) Let $p(x)=a_1x^2+a_3$ and $q(x)=b_1x^2+b_3$ where $p(x),q(x) \in\Bbb{R}_2[x]$ and $a_i,b_i\in\Bbb{R},\space i=\{1,..,n\}$
$$
p(x)+q(x)=(a_1+b_1)x^2+(a_3+b_3),\space a_i+b_i\in\Bbb{R}
$$

Thus the set $W$ is closed under addition.

(ii) Let $p(x)=a_1x^2+a_3$ where $p(x)\in\Bbb{R}_2[x]$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$
$$
\lambda p(x)=\lambda(a_1x^2+a_3)=\lambda a_1x^2+\lambda a_3,\space\lambda a_i\in\Bbb{R}
$$

Thus the set,$W$, is closed under scalar multiplication.

Since we have proven that the two conditions of a subspace, $W\subseteq\Bbb{R[x]}$, so $W$ is a vector space. $\blacksquare$

Have I got the right idea? Any feedback and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be correct. You can also notice directly that $W$ is linearly spanned by $x^2$ and $1$, and hence is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}[X]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours is correct. But I guess it is much easier if you observe that:

> If $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $p(x) = p(-x)$ and $q(x) = q(-x)$, then
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> (\alpha p)(x) &= \alpha p(x) = \alpha p(-x) = (\alpha p)(-x)
> \\
> (p + q)(x) &= p(x) + q(x) = p(-x) + q(-x) = (p+q)(-x).
> \end{align*}$$

Therefore, it is a subspace.